# Crash with thrust::min_element on thrust::device_vector (CUDA Thrust)

Tags: cuda, thrust

The following CUDA Thrust program crashes:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>

int main(void)
{
  thrust::device_vector<int> vec;
  for (int i(0); i < 1000; ++i) {
    vec.push_back(i);
  }

  thrust::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7650b9bc in test_thrust.exe: Microsoft C++
exception:thrust::system::system_error at memory location 0x0017f178..

In `checked_cudaMemcpy()` in `trivial_copy.inl`.
```

If I add `#include <thrust/sort.h>` and replace `min_element` with `sort`, it does not crash.

I'm using CUDA 4.1 on Windows 7 64-bit, compute_20,sm_20 (Fermi), Debug build. In a Release build, I am not getting the crash and min_element finds the correct element.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in Thrust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce the error using debug mode targeting Compute Capability 2.0 (i.e `nvcc -G0 -arch=sm_20`).  The bug does not reproduce in release mode or when targeting Compute Capability 1.x devices, which generally suggests a code-generation problem instead of a bug in the library.  Wherever the fault lies, I'd encourage you to [submit a bug report](http://forums.developer.nvidia.com/devforum/discussion/146/how-to-report-a-cuda-bug/p1) so this issue gets the attention it deserves.  In the meantime, I'd suggest compiling in release mode, which is more rigorously tested.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report. #72796.

Comment: @RogerDahl Where can I find that bug report? The nvdeveloper site (although it says all bugs are publicly visible) doesn't bring back any results when I search for bugs

Comment: @flipchart I wasn't able to find the bug either, after registering it. But I did get an email from an NVIDIA engineer saying that they had reproduced it and that it had been forwarded to the appropriate team.

Comment: NVIDIA has kindly notified me that this issue has been fixed in CUDA 4.2.